# Change folder permission for apache on VPS

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, permissions

Symfony 2 config keeps saying

> Major problems have been detected and must be fixed before continuing
>   : Change the permissions of the "app/cache/" directory so that the web
>   server can write into it. Change the permissions of the "app/logs/"
>   directory so that the web server can write into it.

My steps:

```
rm -rf app/cache/*
rm -rf app/logs/*

chown -R www-data:www-data app/cache
chown -R www-data:www-data app/logs
```

Via ftp I change permisson on this folders to `777`. Apache is runnung as www-data with www-data as group.

But the folders are still not writable and symfony 2 still prints this messages. Any ideas why?

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 Server, Apache 2 and PHP 5.3.x. And since I am on VPS I cannot add acl to mount options.

```
ls -al app/cache
```

gives

```
total 8
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data 4096 May 25 00:10 .
drwxrwxr-x 6 www-data www-data 4096 May 25 00:10 ..

ls -al app/cache
```

gives

```
total 64
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data  4096 May 25 00:10 .
drwxrwxr-x 6 www-data www-data  4096 May 25 00:10 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 40235 May 23 06:33 dev.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 15029 May 23 06:14 prod.log
```

Command

```
ps aux | grep apache
```

gives

```
root     12012  0.0  0.8 257952 18356 ?        Ss   20:32   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 12013  0.0  0.2 154324  4836 ?        S    20:32   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 12019  0.0  1.5 278124 32924 ?        S    20:32   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 12020  0.2  1.5 278116 33348 ?        S    20:32   0:02 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 12171  0.0  1.5 278380 33172 ?        S    20:37   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 12173  0.2  1.5 277568 32740 ?        S    20:37   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 12175  0.0  1.5 278392 33396 ?        S    20:38   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 12178  0.3  1.5 277604 32816 ?        S    20:38   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 12204  0.2  1.5 277832 33048 ?        S    20:39   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 12210  0.5  1.8 283748 38960 ?        S    20:40   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 12212  0.3  1.5 277832 33088 ?        S    20:40   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 12214  0.2  1.5 278132 33352 ?        S    20:40   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 12215  0.0  0.5 258216 10780 ?        S    20:40   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 12223  0.0  0.5 258084 10676 ?        S    20:42   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     12227  0.0  0.0   6164   664 pts/0    S+   20:44   0:00 grep apache
```

Any ideas how to deal with this problem?

Comment: Can you add the results for `ls -al app/cache` and `ls -al app/logs/` to your opening post??

Comment: ok see my update

Comment: Are you sure the directories you have fixed permissions for is the same directories targeted by the application?

Comment: Well the message says clearly that cache and logs folders have no write permissions and there are located in the app directory of symfony2 installation. So I cd in /var/www/mysite/ and change permissions...

Comment: what is your apache vhost config? is php running as cgi or as mod_php?

Comment: It is running as mod_php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that plesk is messing up permissions. I removed the domain from plesk and created my own vhost. Now everything works just like expected.

Answer (score 1):

First, as others have said, are you examining the right files?

The error message from Symfony is poor. It should specify the full path of the files it cannot access. You can try using `strace` of `lsof` to find the files.

Second, is php running as `www-data`?

If you're using `mod_php`, then php runs as the user running apache. But have you checked using ps or top what that user is?

Third, are the old files held open somehow?

In UNIX a file can be open even after removal, and only gets removed completely after all open file handles are closed. Apache/php restart or reboot should take care of this.

Fourth, are you running apparmor/selinux?

Try disabling them first.

Comment: Apache is running as www-data. I restarted apache. apparmor/selinux are not installed. Still same problem...

Comment: are you using mod_php? or some other method of running php?

Answer (score 1):

What are the permissions on `/var/www/mysite`? It needs to be at least executable by the www-data user for that user to access its contents:

```
$ chmod o+x /var/www/mysite
```

Comment: Command does not help, still same problem

Answer (score -1):

Maybe some folders above has no appropriate rights. Check permisions for /var and /var/www.